# Postgres lead window with a series index

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

So I'm working with a table of instruments and their historic closing prices and I'm trying to match a day with an arbitrary number of days in the future's closing price.  To do this I'm trying to use the lead function with a generated series's index.

```
select subq.*, lead(subq.close, x) over w, lead(subq.date, x) over w, x from 
  select instrument_id, close, timestamp::date as date from 
    instrument_data_daily order by instrument_id, date) as subq, 
  generate_series(2, 5) as x 
window w as (PARTITION BY instrument_id ORDER BY date);
```

However this provides what I consider to be incorrect results:

```
 instrument_id |    close    |    date    |    lead     |    lead    | x 
---------------|-------------|------------|-------------|------------|---
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 | 2
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 | 3
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 | 4
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 | 5
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 | 2
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 | 3
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 | 4
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 | 5
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 | 2
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 | 3
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 | 4
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10 | 5
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 | 2
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10 | 3
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10 | 4
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    21499.98 | 2014-12-11 | 5
```

Note that the lead dates for indexes 3 and 4 are the same.

The underlying query generates a table with no duplicates:

```
select instrument_id, close, timestamp::date as date from 
  instrument_data_daily order by instrument_id, date;
```

Provides the following results:

```
 instrument_id |    close    |    date    
---------------+-------------+------------
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09
           801 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10
           801 |    21499.98 | 2014-12-11
           801 |    23100.00 | 2014-12-12
           801 |    23300.04 | 2014-12-15
```

So we can see that the underlying data doesn't contain any problems with duplicates, and that the generated series index, x, is where I'm expecting it to be.  Any ideas as to why the window would pull the wrong index?

(Data set is truncated to fit the example, but it's about a quarter of a million rows deep, making joins expensive).

edit: (Adding in expected results for clarity)
However the expected results are that each date is paired with the correct amount of lead indexed based on x, as follows:  (Note this is manually created, query has not yet been updated)

```
 instrument_id |    close    |    date    |    lead     |    lead    | x 
---------------|-------------|------------|-------------|------------|---
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 | 2
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 | 3
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 | 4
           801 |    34499.96 | 2014-12-04 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10 | 5
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-08 | 2
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 | 3
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10 | 4
           801 |    31599.99 | 2014-12-05 |    21499.98 | 2014-12-11 | 5
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 | 2
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10 | 3
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    21499.98 | 2014-12-11 | 4
           801 |    28599.99 | 2014-12-08 |    23100.00 | 2014-12-12 | 5
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    23399.95 | 2014-12-10 | 2
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    21499.98 | 2014-12-11 | 3
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    23100.00 | 2014-12-12 | 4
           801 |    25800.04 | 2014-12-09 |    23300.04 | 2014-12-15 | 5
```

We should actually update the generated series to be from 1 to x, where x is maximal lookahead desired.  However the same overlapping lead results occur for any nontrivial series results.

Comment: whats your expected result?..

Comment: Updating for expected results